# Zoom to particular area in svg using mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, svg, zooming, mousewheel

I have a simple svg map embedded in my asp.net site. I want to zoom-out and zoom-in that map using mousewheel.

I have somewhat achieved zoom functionality using mousewheel.js.

But the problem is, i couldn't get the map to zoom to particular area. instead whole map grows.

SVG

```
<div id="divmap">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black"
  stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>     
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$("#divmap").bind('mousewheel', function (event, delta) {
                var divheight = $('svg').height();
                if ((divheight - 50) > 100) {
                    var delta_px = delta > 0 ? "+=50" : "-=50";
                    if (delta < 10) {
                        var options = { height: delta_px, width: delta_px };
                        $('svg').css({
                            width: delta_px,
                            height: delta_px

                        });                        
                    }
                }
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tjq8X/1/

How to implement zoom to particular area like we have in google maps?

Comment: I found this library [svgpan](https://github.com/talos/jquery-svgpan "svgpan") may what you want.